# Jade - Only output a property if defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I've not doubt somebody will have covered this:

```
id="#{data.id}"
```

**Output**

```
<input id="undefined"> //if I haven't defined id
```

**Desired**

```
//If ID is undefined
<input>
//If ID is defined
<input id="someID">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply code:

```
input(id= data.id)
```

When the `id` is `undefined`, a falsy value, Jade won't add the attribute to the tag. This feature is also useful when you are setting *property* attributes like `checked` or `selected`.

Another option is using the `&attributes` syntax:

```
- var attrs = data.id ? {id: data.id} : null;
input&attributes(attrs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code within an `if ... else` statement so that you wrap up the case where your `id` is not defined:

```js
id = data.id
if id === "undefined"
  input#someID
else
  input#id
```